# Set special price as percentage

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, special-price, percentage

Is it possible to modify Magento 1.9.0.1 so that special price could be set as percentage from the original price? In other words we could set special price to be for example 80% of the original price.

Comment: need to set in magento backend or show only in frontend?

Comment: @RamaChandran Need to set it in Magento backend and in such fashion that I could mass edit it.